# PostGIS bbox with two tables

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I am new to using PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

I have two tables that I've imported from two shapefiles. One table is based on points called "shape_points" and the other based on polygons called "shape_polygons".

Now I want to get the bounding box of all records, so I use the next query for the table "shape_points":

```
`SELECT box2d(geom) FROM shape_points;`
```

AND this for the table "shape_polygons":

```
`SELECT box2d(geom) FROM shape_polygons;`
```

At this point both querys works perfect.

So the big problem is when I do a UNION of the two tables:

```
`SELECT box2d(geom) FROM shape_points
  UNION
 SELECT box2d(geom) FROM shape_polygons`
```

I get the next error:

**"ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type box2d"**

What is the problem?

Comment: Should you first union the geometry of the two tables then do the box2d on the union?

Comment: ST_Envelope could be better for you http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely clear whether you want a list of the bounding boxes for each and every record in the two tables, or to know the overall bounding box of all your records. A way to fix the query you are trying to run is to use UNION ALL - the SQL UNION operator normally removes identical records from the two sets, whereas UNION ALL does not, and so will not require an equality operator:

```
SELECT box2d(geom) FROM shape_points
  UNION ALL
SELECT box2d(geom) FROM shape_polygons
```

But I suspect that what you are really after is a single overall bounding box, which you can get using the ST_extent() aggregate function, documented here: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html

I haven't tested this but something like the following should work:

```
WITH all_geoms AS(
    SELECT st_extent(geom) as extent FROM shape_points
      UNION ALL
    SELECT st_extent(geom) as extent FROM shape_polygons)
SELECT st_extent(extent) FROM all_geoms
```

Comment: That is exactly what i looking for, works like a dream! Thank you! First my needs are only a table with all the points and polygons with the bbox for each row. But seeing your second example i realized that i also need the total bbox for the extent of the map, thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a box that contains your entire dataset, you can union the bounding boxes of each geometry, but you can't use the native SQL UNION (without ALL) function to union BOXes because, as it says, they have no equality operator -- there's no way to check for duplicates. However, PostGIS *can* perform a geometric union on them, so this will work:

```
SELECT ST_Union(box2d(geom)) FROM (
    SELECT geom FROM shape_points 
    UNION 
    SELECT geom FROM shape_polygons
)
```

Even if UNION did work, you'd just get a list of the BOXes for each geometry (which, in the case of a point, is degenerate), not a single BOX.

---

In light of the comments: this answer is just meant to illustrate the difference between `ST_Union` and `UNION` and why `box2d` doesn't work with the latter. The accepted answer is the fastest one.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, works perfect, i just edit a little the query for my needs: SELECT ST_Extent(box2d(geom)) FROM (
    SELECT geom FROM shape_points
    UNION 
    SELECT geom FROM shape_polygons
)as extent

Comment: ST_Union is overkill if you are only worried about the bboxes (extents) of the geometries. It is intended to union complete polygons and returns a complete polygon. While the bounding box of the result returned from this query would be the right answer, it would take much more time and memory to calculate than using st_extent() as in my answer.

Comment: Furthermore, using the SQL UNION instead of UNION ALL means that every shape in the table would need to be checked for equality, in order to remove duplicates. While this check should be fast in this case, since the tables have different types of geometry, if both tables had polygons it would be very slow, and in either case is unnecessary to produce the desired result.